# How to implement a CustomKeySerializer

Tags: scala, json4s

If I try to serialize the case class:

```
case class C(map: Map[Boolean, String])
```

I get the exception:

```
org.json4s.package$MappingException: Do not know how to serialize key of type class java.lang.Boolean. Consider implementing a CustomKeySerializer
```

I cannot find any documentation anywhere as to how I should implement a CustomKeySerializer. Could someone point me to a guide?

Comment: I think there is the same reason as in question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64914995/cannot-deserialize-a-tuple/64931695
`boolean` can't be a key in JSON-objects, but in serialized `C` it would be in key: `{ "map" : { true : "some_string", false : "antoher_one" } }` but is is invalid. I would advice do not use `Boolean` as key type in serialized to JSON structures.

Comment: The error message is misleading. You don't implement CustomKeySerializer, you just create new instance and add it to you formats. Check its constructor signature.

Comment: Can you please create [mre]? It is hard to answer it like this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [json standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), [keys of an object must be strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muc04.png), and [a `String` must be wrapped with quotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYKKm.png).

If you want to convert a supported type, you can simply do:

```
case class C1(map: Map[String, Boolean]) {
  val json = "map" -> map
}
val c1 = C1(Map("true" -> true, "false" -> false))
println(pretty(render(c1.json)))
```

The output is:

```
{
  "map":{
    "true":true,
    "false":false
  }
}
```

But if you want to convert an **unsupported type**, you need to make the conversion yourself. For example you can do:

```
case class C(map: Map[Boolean, String]) {
  val json = "map" -> map.map(kvp => (kvp._1.toString, kvp._2))
}
val c = C(Map(true -> "true", false -> "false"))
println(pretty(render(c.json)))
```

And the output is:

```
{
  "map":{
    "true":"true",
    "false":"false"
  }
}
```

In order to do all of that you need to import:

```
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/G84ijtb2Sl2ukmULhZCo9g/5).

Comment: What you write about keys being strings - this is exactly why a key serializer is needed.